# Modbus TCP Slave Thread - set & get registers values

Tags: java, master-slave, modbus, modbus-tcp, predix

According to this [howToModbusSlave](http://jamod.sourceforge.net/kb/tcp_slave_howto.html) I am trying to build my own modbus slave with registers of chosen value (later I wanna fill these values with data from monitored device using python/jython) and send them away using Predix (cloud platform). Since I am a modbus greenhorn, I still cant find a way how to add my chosen values into my register holders.

Here is the my Slave thread I use to provide data for the Master on localhost:502 :

```
public class SimpleApp {

public static void main(String args[]) {
try {

//1. The important instances and variables
ModbusTCPListener listener = null;
SimpleProcessImage spi = null;
int port = 502;


//2. Prepare a process image
spi = new SimpleProcessImage();

//I dont understand this part, why do i need it?
spi.addDigitalOut(new SimpleDigitalOut(true));
spi.addDigitalOut(new SimpleDigitalOut(false));
spi.addDigitalIn(new SimpleDigitalIn(false));
spi.addDigitalIn(new SimpleDigitalIn(true));
spi.addDigitalIn(new SimpleDigitalIn(false));
spi.addDigitalIn(new SimpleDigitalIn(true)); 

//setting up register holders, gonna ask no 10,11,20 and 21 as set in the data node config
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    int value = 15;
    SimpleInputRegister sr = new SimpleInputRegister(value);
        spi.addRegister(sr);
    }

    //3. Set the image on the coupler
    ModbusCoupler.getReference().setProcessImage(spi);
    ModbusCoupler.getReference().setMaster(false);
    ModbusCoupler.getReference().setUnitID(15);   //15

    //4. Create a listener with 3 threads in pool
    listener = new ModbusTCPListener(1); //no of threads
    listener.setPort(port);
    listener.start();  

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Data nodes config:

```
   <channel protocol="TCP_IP" tcpIpAddress="127.0.0.1" tcpIpPort="502">
        <unit id="1">
            <register name="Node-1-1" dataType="INTEGER" address="10" registerType="HOLDING" description="temperature"/>
            <register name="Node-1-2" dataType="DECIMAL" address="11" registerType="HOLDING" description="pressure"/>
        </unit>
        <unit id="2">
            <register name="Node-2-1" dataType="INTEGER" address="20" registerType="HOLDING" description="temperature"/>
            <register name="Node-2-2" dataType="INTEGER" address="21" registerType="HOLDING" description="pressure"/>
        </unit>
    </channel>
```

I get theses transfers ("output"):

```
[{"address":"com.ge.dspmicro.machineadapter.modbus://127.0.0.1:502/2/20","datatype":"INTEGER","name":"Node-2-1","category":"REAL","value":655370,"timestamp":1464006550991,"quality":"NOT_SUPPORTED (20000000) "},
{"address":"com.ge.dspmicro.machineadapter.modbus://127.0.0.1:502/1/10","datatype":"INTEGER","name":"Node-1-1","category":"REAL","value":655370,"timestamp":1464006550992,"quality":"NOT_SUPPORTED (20000000) "}]
```

**Main Questions:**

1) where are the data from Node 1-2 and 2-2 (missing in the output)?

2) how can I edit the values the are sent from the registers? (why do i get "value":655370?)

*Optional Qustions: (things i didnt understand in [documentation](http://jamod.sourceforge.net/api/net/wimpi/modbus/procimg/Register.html))*

3) what does the class simpleDigitalOut/In stand for?

4) what does the ModbusCoupler.getReference().setUnitID(value) stand for? (it clearly doesnt have to do anything in common with unitID of data nodes

5) what is the difference between SimpleInputRegister and SimpleRegister class?

Comment: This question has been here for awhile, did you end up finding a solution already or did you try asking in the Java Modbus Library developer forums?

Answer (score -1):

This is a partial answer:

1) You need to add the nodes to the `dataSubscriptionConfig` tag below in the `config.xml` file

2) Here is where you are setting the value: `int value = 15;`  - You need to implement a way to send dynamic values